# PHP Mysql - creating own banking system

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, locking, banking

I am working on a project where users will buy "coins" with real money. They will also be able to sell these coins for real money in a transactional system. They might even be able to send coins to other users. This is going to be written in PHP. I understand mysql tranactions but i am not 100% sure whats this needs to be 100% from concurrency bugs. I have created pseudo code, which i believe has a flaw in it.

```
    function withdraw($id, $amount_to_withdraw) {
       $ret = false;
       $balance = $db->getBalanceById($id);

       $this->makeSureAmountIsNotNegative($amount_to_withdraw);

       $new_balance = $balance - $amount_to_withdraw;

       if ($new_balance >= 0.00) {
        try {
             $db->startTransaction();

            // THIS IS WHERE THE FLAW IS!!!
            $db->do("UPDATE account SET balance = ? WHERE id = ?", array($new_balance, $id));

            $db->commit();

            $ret = true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $db->rollback();
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

From my understanding, its possible in PHP for another request to execute before this is completely finished and could possibly set the balance to below zero and other bad concurrency bugs.
How do i write this code so that it is safe from these bugs.
Do i need row level mysql locking like:

```
// ROW LEVEL LOCKING FOR UPDATE
$balance = $db->select("SELECT balance FROM account WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE;", array($id));
```

Thanks
Brian

Comment: Did you mean to write `SET balance = ?`?

Comment: Yep, thanks..edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the query that gets the old balance and the one that sets the new balance in the same transaction. So you need to put `$db->startTransaction()` before `$db->getBalance($id);`, and put all this inside the `try` block.

```
function withdraw($id, $amount_to_withdraw) {
    $ret = false;

    try {
        $db->startTransaction();

        $balance = $db->getBalanceById($id);

        $this->makeSureAmountIsNotNegative($amount_to_withdraw);

        $new_balance = $balance - $amount_to_withdraw;

        if ($new_balance >= 0.00) {
            $db->do("UPDATE account SET balance = ? WHERE id = ?", array($new_balance, $id));

            $ret = true;
        }
        $db->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $db->rollback();
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

But a simpler way is to do the subtraction in the `UPDATE` query, rather than doing two queries.

```
$db->do("UPDATE account SET balance = balance - ? 
        WHERE id = ? AND balance >= ?", array($amount_to_withdraw, $id, $amount_to_withdraw));
```

You don't need to create a transaction explicitly for this, since a statement is always its own transaction.

Comment: OK, if i put the subtraction in the query what will guarantee that the new balance is > 0.00?...Lets say balance is 100, wont mysql gladly execute this: balance = 100 - 101, which would result in a negative balance?

Comment: I don't see anything in your original code that prevents that. You just check if the amount to withdraw is negative, not if `$new_balance` is negative.

Comment: $balance = $db->getBalanceById($id);

       $this->makeSureAmountIsNotNegative($amount_to_withdraw);

       $new_balance = $balance - $amount_to_withdraw;

       if ($new_balance >= 0.00) {

Comment: Oops, missed that. I've updated the answer to show how to do that in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The only problem is that you can't set `$ret` this way. Does your DB class provide a way to call `PDOStatement::rowCount()`? That will tell you if any rows were found and updated.

Comment: Ya thats the easy part, im not too worried about that.

Comment: I suggest having `DB::do()` end with `return $stmt->rowCount();` when it's not a `SELECT` query

Comment: ok cool..just to be clear...this should be all i really need for a highly concurrent environment where someone might be trying to hit our servers to withdraw more coins then they actually have?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. This is what transactions are all about.